# When launching jdeveloper a cmd window appears

Tags: java, cmd, jdeveloper, launch

When I launch **jdeveloper** a black command window appears with it, and never disappears.
If I close it, **Jdeveloper** closes as well:

[image]

This window shows the log messages, where **jdeveloper** shows them as well in its Messages-log window.

How can I prevent this window from appearing.

The version: 11.1.1.6.0
The build: 6229

**EDIT:**

OK, *TheNawaKer* helped me in finding the following information:

Start Oracle JDeveloper from the command line by running one of the following commands:

1. JDEV_HOME\jdeveloper\jdeveloper.exe
2. JDEV_HOME\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdevw.exe
3. JDEV_HOME\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdev.exe (to display a console window
   for internal diagnostic information)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use JDev in debug mode. The console displays all logs of JDev. (jdev.exe or jdev64.exe on windows)

Run this executable to start JDev in normal mode:

- JDEV_HOME\jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdevw.exe (or jdev64W.exe if on 64 bit windows)

*Side note: JDEV_HOME is the location where you installed JDeveloper.*

*The reference documentation: [Oracle Jdevlopper Post Install](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/jdev/OJDIG/post_install.htm)*